# Создать таблицы из *.dtd или *.xsd

Tags: sql, sql-server, xsd

Стоит задача создать связанные таблицы в *MS SQL*, структура которых взята из [`shops.dtd`](http://partner.market.yandex.ru/pages/help/shops.dtd) (или созданной на его основе `shops.xsd`).

Как это сделать в автоматическом режиме (если, конечно, вообще есть такая возможность)?

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы из схемы можно было создать таблицы в автоматическом режиме, схема должна быть нужным образом подготовлена.

В таком случае у вас получится автоматически создать таблицы и заполнить их данными из XML-файла, соответствующего схеме.

Инструмент для подобных операций называется SQLXMLBulkLoad - вы в сети без труда найдете и сам инструмент и инструкции по его использованию, вот один из примеров:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/monicafrintu/2007/06/12/how-to-create-tables-in-a-database-using-an-xsd-schema-and-sqlxmlbulkload/